# IOs App Languages

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Can someone help with this issue. An app that we have developed has only one language, this is evident in the itunes connect development dashboard.

However, when viewing the app in the app store it shows English and German. I have looked everywhere in the itunes connect dashboard but cannot see where this second language is being pulled from. It only shows a primary language which is English.

All help will be much appreaciated.

Many thanks,

Aaron

Comment: With "viewing", do you mean on the AppStore?

Answer (score 1):

Is that only set to english??

http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

[image]